# Calculate mean for vector of points

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a vector of a 2-dimensional points in OpenCV

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> points;
```

I would like to calculate the mean values for x and y coordinates in `points`. Something like:

```
cv::Point2f mean_point; //will contain mean values for x and y coordinates
mean_point = some_function(points);
```

This would be simple in Matlab. But I'm not sure if I can utilize some high level OpenCV functions to accomplish the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why isn't a for loop being used?

Comment: I can use a for loop. But I was wondering if there is a high level function in OpenCV or std library to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`InputArray` does a good job here. You can simply call

```
cv::Mat mean_;
cv::reduce(points, mean_, 01, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
// convert from Mat to Point - there may be even a simpler conversion, 
// but I do not know about it.
cv::Point2f mean(mean_.at<float>(0,0), mean_.at<float>(0,1));
```

Details:

In the newer OpenCV versions, the `InputArray` data type is introduced. This way, one can send as parameters to an OpenCV function either matrices (cv::Mat) either vectors. A `vector<Vec3f>` will be interpreted as a float matrix with three channels, one row, and the number of columns equal to the vector size. Because no data is copied, this transparent conversion is very fast.

The advantage is that you can work with whatever data type fits better in your app, while you can still use OpenCV functions to ease mathematical operations on it.

Comment: Thanks! However, conversion from Mat to Point using `cv::Point2f mean(mean_(0), mean_(1));` didn't work.

Comment: This one should: `cv::Point2f mean(mean_.at<float>(0), mean_.at<float>(1));`

Comment: tested, it works. double checked `cv:reduce(...)` parameters - should be `cv::reduce(points, mean_, CV_REDUCE_AVG, 1);`, thx.

Comment: Maybe the definition has changed, but currently reduce is `void reduce(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int dim, int rtype, int dtype=-1 )`  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce - rtype comes after dim so that should be `cv::reduce(points, mean_, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG);`  I think some other changes are necessary to make this run without exceptions I'll follow up with.

Comment: simpler way to convert from Mat to Point
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18523894/conversion-of-3x1-or-1x3-cvmat-to-cvpoint3d

Answer (score 11):

Since OpenCV's `Point_` already defines `operator+`, this should be fairly simple. First we sum the values:

```
cv::Point2f zero(0.0f, 0.0f);

cv::Point2f sum  = std::accumulate(points.begin(), points.end(), zero);
```

Then we divide to get the average:

```
Point2f mean_point(sum.x / points.size(), sum.y / points.size());
```

...or we could use `Point_`'s `operator*`:

```
Point2f mean_point(sum * (1.0f / points.size()));
```

Unfortunately, at least as far as I can see, `Point_` doesn't define `operator /`, so we need to multiply by the inverse instead of dividing by the size.

Answer (score 6):

You can use stl's [std::accumulate](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html) as follows:

```
cv::Point2f sum = std::accumulate(
    points.begin(), points.end(), // Run from begin to end
    cv::Point2f(0.0f,0.0f),       // Initialize with a zero point
    std::plus<cv::Point2f>()      // Use addition for each point (default)
);
cv::Point2f mean = sum / points.size(); // Divide by count to get mean
```

Comment: looks like an average, not mean

Comment: What's the distinction? Average is a synonym for arithmetic mean.

Answer (score 0):

Add them all up and divide by the total number of points.