# Conversion of 3x1 or 1x3 cv::Mat to cv::Point3d?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm dealing with some code in which a do a lot of 3x3 matrix multiplications an also some translation of 3d points using rotation matrices, etc. I decided to use OpenCV core functionalities for the mathematical operations. The possibility to use the recent constructor added to the `cv::Mat` class to convert a `cv::Point3d` directly to a 3x1 `cv::Mat` reduces and simplifies the code greatly.

What I am wondering now is if there is a simple way to convert a 3x1 or 1x3 `cv::Mat` to an `cv::Point3d`? I always can do something like:

```
cv::Mat mat(3,1,CV_64FC1);
cv::Point3d p (mat.at<double>(0,0), mat.at<double>(1,0), mat.at<double>(2,0));
```

or

```
cv::Mat mat(3,1,CV_64FC1);
const double *data = mat.ptr<double>(0);
cv::Point3d p (data[0], data[1], data[2]);
```

I am very worried about the performance (avoid the 3 calls to `at` method).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cv::Point3d` has a constructor which allows direct creation from `cv::Mat`:

```
cv::Mat mat(3,1,CV_64FC1);
cv::Point3d p(mat);
```

Another possibility you may not have considered is using `cv::Matx` instead of `cv::Mat` for your mathematical operations. I find it is easier to use, and offers more functionality, like multiplication of `Point` types without needing a conversion:

```
cv::Point3d p(1,2,3);
cv::Matx33d m = cv::Matx33d::eye();
cv::Point3d p2 = m * p;
```

`cv::Matx` is also statically allocated, rather than dynamically (like `cv::Mat`), in case you *really* need that extra little bit of performance. However, as in all performance-related advice: make sure what you're optimizing is actually a bottleneck by profiling.

Comment: Great! I was looking in the opencv core.hpp header for a constructor for the Point_ class like:

`Point_(const Mat& sz);`

As I didn't found it I thought there was no way to do it. Furthermore I didn't notice the existence of 

`Point_(const Vec<_Tp, 2>& v);`

The usage of Matx seems to be very useful for my purposes. Thanks a lot!

Comment: to be exact, there is no constructor for `Point_<T>`/`Point3_<T>` that takes a `cv::Mat`, rather there is an implicit [cast operator](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp#L1856) in `cv::Mat` that converts it to other fixed-size classes like `Vec` or `Matx` (`Vec` is accepted by Point constructor)

Comment: I wonder why we can transform `cv::Point` with matrix, but not `cv::Vec`. In the latter case we need to convert `cv::Vec` into `cv::Point` first.

Comment: @MaksymGanenko It may be an oversight. However, the most common use for `cv::Vec` types is element access for multi-channel images, rather than as a mathematical construct.